# Integration testing of a Spring Cloud application with the AWS Parameter Store

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-parameter-store

How to perform integration testing of a Spring Boot application reading properties from the AWS Parameter Store (dependency `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config`).

Should the AWS Parameter Store integration be disabled in integration tests?

How to use local server (or mock) instead of the real AWS Parameter Store in integration tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually integration with the AWS Parameter Store should be disabled in integration tests for simplicity and performance. Instead, load test properties from a file (e.g., `src/test/resources/test.properties`)

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "aws.paramstore.enabled=false")
@TestPropertySource("classpath:/test.properties")
public class SampleTests {
  //...
}
```

If individual tests need to check integration with the AWS Parameter Store use [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) and [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) an easy-to-use local AWS cloud stack for Docker.

Add a configuration class creating custom `ssmClient` bean of type `AWSSimpleSystemsManagement` configured to use LocalStack instead of a default one declared in `org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.paramstore.AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration` using the real AWS Parameter Store.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration {

  public static final LocalStackContainer AWS_SSM_CONTAINER = initContainer();

  public static LocalStackContainer initContainer() {
    LocalStackContainer container = new LocalStackContainer().withServices(SSM);
    container.start();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(container::stop));
    return container;
  }

  @Bean
  public AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient() {
    return AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(AWS_SSM_CONTAINER.getEndpointConfiguration(SSM))
        .withCredentials(AWS_SSM_CONTAINER.getDefaultCredentialsProvider())
        .build();
  }
}
```

As far as `AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator` is a loaded by a Spring Cloud "bootstrap" context, you need to add a configuration class to the bootstrap context by adding to the file `src/test/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` the following entry

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.example.test.AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration
```

The same approach can be used for mocking `ssmClient` using Mockito.